# Convert function from matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am new to the python. I have a problem to convert this simple function in matlab to the python. Here is the original matlab code

```
function Cmode=my_map(image1)

[D,A,B] = size(image1)
crp = image1((1:D),(A:-1:1),(B:-1:1));
Cmode1 = max(crp,[],1);
Cmode = permute(Cmode1,[3 2 1]);
```

The input file is 3d matrix. I tried this but failed

```
def cmode(image1):
   [D,A,B] = np.shape(image1)
   crp = image1[(0,D),(A,-1,0), (B,-1,0)]
   cmode1 = np.max(crp,[],1)
   c = np.transpose( np.expand_dims(cmode1, axis=2), (2, 1, 0) )
   return c
```

here is the error

```
crp = d3image[(0,D),(A,-1,0), (B,-1,0)]
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together      with shapes (2,) (3,) (3,)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You should change the title of this question to better reflect what the function *does*. That way it may help more SO users in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`D`, `A` and `B` are unnecessary, they are only being used to read the image from end to end (second and third axes read backwards). In NumPy that notation would be

```
crp = image1[:, ::-1, ::-1]
```

Secondly, the second argument for `max` won't work, instead you should use

```
cmode1 = np.max(crp, axis=1)
```

Comment: `np.max(image1,axis=0, keepdims=1)` because MATLAB keeps the dims, to be strictly coherent with MATLAB's version. And then you would need something  like : `np.max(image1,axis=0, keepdims=1)[0].T` to remove that extra dim. If you are in hurry to get to the final destination : `np.max(image1,axis=0).T`.